# Problemas com cálculos com jquery.maskMoney

Tags: javascript, jquery, maskmoney

Galera tenho um javascript que faz o cálculo perfeito entre 3 inputs. Sendo eles.

1- CUSTO, recebe o custo de um produto
2- VENDA, recebe p preço de venda, e calculo automaticamente a margem de lucro
3- %LUCRO, recebe o lucro e calcula automaticamente o preço de venda.

O problema e que estou tentando usar o plugin `jquery.maskMoney` no input LUCRO, e quando uso ele o calculo do preço de venda não acontece. Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Para ver o código funcionando perfeitamente basta excluir o seguinte código.

```
$(function() {
    $(".margens2").maskMoney({
        allowNegative: true,
        thousands: '.',
        decimal: ',',
        affixesStay: false
    }).trigger('mask.maskMoney');
});
```

Segue o meu código:

```js
$(function() {
        $(".margens").maskMoney({
            allowNegative: true,
            thousands: '.',
            decimal: ',',
            affixesStay: false
        }).trigger('mask.maskMoney');
    });

$(document).ready(function() {

  // Faz o calculo da margem com base no valor
  $(".valor").on("input", function() {
    // Margem
    var valor = $(this).val();
    var valorCorrigido = parseFloat(adicionarPontos(valor));
    var valorFloat = parseFloat(valorCorrigido) || 0.0;

    // Custo  
    var valorCusto = $('#custo').val();
    var valorCustoCorrigido = parseFloat(removerPontos(valorCusto));
    var valorCustoFloat = parseFloat(valorCustoCorrigido) || 0.0;

    // Calculo
    var calculo = (parseFloat(valorFloat) - parseFloat(valorCustoFloat)) / parseFloat(valorCustoFloat) * 100;
    var inputMargem = $(this).attr("margem");

    var resultadoMonetario = calculo.toFixed(2).replace(".", ",");

    $("#" + inputMargem).val(resultadoMonetario).trigger('blur');
  });

  // Faz o calculo do valor com base na margem
  $(".margem").on("input", function() {
    // Margem
    var valorMargem = $(this).val();
    var valorMargemCorrigido = parseFloat(adicionarPontos(valorMargem));
    var valorMargemFloat = parseFloat(valorMargemCorrigido) || 0.0;

    // Custo
    var valorCusto = $('#custo').val();
    var valorCustoCorrigido = parseFloat(removerPontos(valorCusto));
    var valorCustoFloat = parseFloat(valorCustoCorrigido) || 0.0;

    // Cálculo
    var calculo = (parseFloat(valorCustoFloat) * parseFloat(valorMargemFloat) / 100) + parseFloat(valorCustoFloat);
    var inputValor = $(this).attr("valor");

    var resultadoMonetario = calculo.toFixed(2).replace(".", ",");

    $("#" + inputValor).val(resultadoMonetario).trigger('blur');
  });

  function removerPontos(valor) {
    valor = valor.replace(".", "");
    valor = valor.replace(",", ".");
    return valor;
  }

  function adicionarPontos(valor) {
    if (valor.length === 1) {
      return valor;
    } else {
      if (valor.length === 2) {
        return valor;
      } else {
        valor = valor.replace(",", "");

        var inteiro = valor.substring(0, valor.length - 2);
        var decimal = valor.substring(valor.length - 2, valor.length);

        return inteiro + "." + decimal;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-maskmoney/3.0.2/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>



<div class='form-group'>
  <label class='control-label' for='custo'>CUSTO*</label>
  <input type='text' class='form_campos form_campos_simples custo' id='custo' name='custo' value="10">
</div>
<div class='form-group'>
  <label class='control-label' for='valor1'>VENDA</label>
  <input type='text' class='form_campos form_campos_numeros valor valores' id='valor1' name='valor1' margem='margem1'>
</div>
<div class='form-group'>
  <label class='control-label' for='margem1'>% LUCRO</label>
  <input type='text' class='form_campos form_campos_numeros margem margens' id='margem1' name='margem1' valor='valor1'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Para resolver seu problema, troque o evento que você está chamando em ".margem" para **keyup** ao invés de **input**.

No seu código está assim:

```
$(".margem").on("input", function() {
```

Mude para:

```
$(".margem").on("keyup", function() {
```

Comment: MUITO BOM, FUNCIONOU 100%